# Analysis of convergence of $\sum \frac{1}{\log^a n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I Need to show that

$$ \sum \frac{1}{(\log n)^a}$$

Diverges for all positive values of a.

My idea is to use the comparasion test, since the ratio test and rpot test are inconclusive. I want tp show that

$$ n^a > ln(n)$$ for values of n bigger than one $n_o$. This looks like a good approach, but i coulsnt find the $n_o$

Thanks in advance

Comment: $\sum=\sum_{n \ge 2}$ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hint: compare with Harmonic series, which diverges

EDIT: consider the function $\frac{\log^k n}{n}$, set $\log n =t, \ n = e^t$. We need to show $a_n = \frac{e^n}{n^k}$ is an increasing function for some $n(k)$. Consider the ratio $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$. After a bit of algebra you can show it is larger than $1$ for $n >\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{k}}}{1-e^{-\frac{1}{k}}}$.

Hence, $e^n >n^k \ \forall \ n> \frac{e^{-\frac{1}{k}}}{1-e^{-\frac{1}{k}}} \Rightarrow n >\log^k n \Rightarrow \frac{1}{n}<\frac{1}{\log^k n}$

Comment: @Giiovanna He is right, one l'Hopital's rule and you are done.

Comment: There are better ways, I'll explain if he asks.

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do, but it is not working. Can you give more details?

Comment: I think I got what to do now, thanks

Comment: Alex, I've tried to  compare with harmonic, but I still dont have a $n_o$. Can you explain it with a little more details?

Comment: Please see the edit

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to find the exact $n_0$ if you use l'Hopital's rule. Suppose you want to take $a = 1$. Then by l'Hopital
$$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} {\ln n \over n} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } {{1 \over n} \over 1} = 0$$
So there will be some $n_0$ for which ${\displaystyle {\ln n \over n} < 1}$ for all $n > n_0$, which is all you need here.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I was thinking to get the serie$ \sum \frac{1}{n^a}$, right? We will have that $\lim (\frac{ln(n)}{n})^a $ will be zero for all the values of a>0. But since $\sum \frac{1}{n^a}$ converges for a>1, doesnt that implies the convergence of the serie for a>1?

Comment: Oh sorry, the comparasion test does not works since the limit is zero. But, I cant see what to do with the inequality you gaveme for values of a bigger than 1

Comment: I can see what you mean:$ \lim \frac{ln^a(n)}{n} =0 $ for all $a>0$. But, how to show this to generic values of a. I know, by l'Hospital, that it will be $\lim a \frac{log^{a-1}(N)}{N}$, but it seems something recursive.

Comment: I've found what I was looking for:http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/712613/prove-that-all-values-satisfy-this-expression/712618

Comment: It's not endlessly recursive... after $k > a$ iterations you have ${\log^{a - k} n \over n}$, and since the exponent $a - n < 0$ it will only decrease faster than ${1 \over n}$. Alternatively, showing ${\log^a n \over n}$ goes to zero is equivalent to showing its ${1 \over a}$th power ${\log n \over n^{1 \over a}}$ goes to zero, which can be done with a single application of l'Hopital.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the integral test, a substitution of $u=\ln(x)$ changes the integral to the equivalent: $$\int_{\ln(2)}^\infty \frac{e^{u}}{u^a} du.$$ l'Hopital's rule tells us that the integrand blows up to infinity for any $a$ and so the integral diverges.

Now recall that the integral test tells us for a decreasing continuous function $f(x)$, the series $\sum_{n=a}^\infty f(n)$ diverges iff the integral $\int_a^\infty f(x) dx$ diverges.

Thus we can conclude that the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$$
\lim_nn^{-s}(\ln n)^a=0 \quad \forall s\in (0,1],
$$
there is some $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$
(\ln n)^a \le n^s \quad \forall n \ge k.
$$
There is no loss of generality in assuming that $k \ge 3$.
Then we have:
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^a}=\sum_{n=2}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^a}+\sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^a}
\ge\sum_{n=2}^{k-1}\frac{1}{(\ln n)^a}+\sum_{n=k}^\infty n^{-s}
\ge\sum_{n=k}^\infty n^{-s}.
$$
Since the series $\sum_{n=k}^\infty n^{-s}$ diverges for $s\in (0,1]$, then 
the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{1}{(\ln n)^a}$ also diverges.